# update different column values with specific value

Tags: java, sql

a table has a column named 'score' with different values.
 |  name  | contact  |  area  |  score |

---

|  james | +222451   | eastp|70      |
 
|  jimmy | +222451   | eestp | 80     |
|   k.josh | +222451  | ecstp | 50    |
|   L.john | +222451  | efstp | 60    |

I want to update all score values with a specific value. eg. update all score values with 10.

therefore value 70 will be 80
value 80 will be 90
value 50 will be 60
value 60 will be 70 
please how do I write a code to achieve this.
 wrote down this but all columns get changed to the same value. please help.

```
int reg = 10; 

try {

    String sql1 = "select Score from db_table where ID=db_table.ID";
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        int ad = rs.getInteger("Score");
        int fad = ad+reg;
        String sql2 = "update db_table set Score='" + fad + "' where _ID=db_table.ID";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
        pst.execute();
    }

} catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
} finally
{
    try
    {
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    } catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```

but anytime is executed, the whole column values are replaced with the same value '10'. instead of each column value should rather be increased by 10. please help

Comment: Hi, you dont need to do select and then update. You can do it in single update. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52243173/2469308
Let me know if it works for you. thanks :)

Comment: ok @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you are stating, please note that in your finally statement the second close wont be executed if the first one errors. This is a common pitfall that has been addressed in Java 8 with the introduction of try-with-resource-close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
UPDATE db_table 
SET score = score + 10
```

So, basically you don't need to `SELECT` all the scores first, and then manipulate them inside Java code, and use `UPDATE` one by one. Instead, change your **try block** in the Java code as follows:

```
try
{
        String sql1 = "UPDATE db_table Set score = score + " + String.valueOf(reg);
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int reg = 10; 
try{
    String sql1="select Score from db_table where ID=db_table.ID";
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        int ad = rs.getInteger("Score");
        int fad = ad+reg;
        String sql2 = "update db_table set Score=Score + "+fad+" where _ID=db_table.ID";
        pst=con.prepareStatement(sql2);
        pst.execute();
    }
}catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}finally{
  try{
    rs.close();
    pst.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e){}
}
```